# getting the most recent value in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I am trying to create **add to faviourate** button with icon.
so far I could make a logic if a user clicked the empty heart icon that it turns to be full heart icon and I was able to locate the item it was clicked on.

So far so good, my issue starts when `products` object recieves only the most recent item that is picked and loses the other items that are previously picked.

so for example If I want to click on 3 items to add them to faviourate, I see that the `console.log(favProduct)` only preserves the most recent item which is in my case number 3 and loses number 1 and 2.

**My Question is** How to get all Items I clicked on and not only the most recent one.

**Edit** This is where I get the product from, check the code below.

```js
import React , { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Row , Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import axios from 'axios'

const HomeScreen = () =>{
    const [products , setProducts]  = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        let componentMounted = true
        const fetchProducts = async () =>{
            const {data} = await axios.get('http://172.30.246.130:5000/api/products')
            if( componentMounted){

                setProducts(data)
            }
        }
        fetchProducts()
        return () =>{
            componentMounted = false
        }
    },[])
    console.log('products' , products)
    return(
        <>
        <h2 className='my-3'>Latest Products</h2>
        <Row>
            {
                products.map((product)=>(
                    <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                    <Product product={product} rating = {product.rating} reviews={product.numReviews}/>
                    </Col>
                ))
            }
        </Row>
        </>
    )
}
export default HomeScreen
```

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const Fav = ({products}) => {
    let [checked , setChecked] = useState(false)
    let[favProduct ,setFavProduct] = useState([])
    const toggle = ()=>{
        (!checked) ? setChecked(true) : setChecked(false)
        setFavProduct([...favProduct,products]) // problem is here

    }
    console.log(favProduct)
    return (
        <>
        <span onClick={toggle}>
            {
                <i className={(checked) ? "fas fa-heart" : "far fa-heart"}></i>
            }
        </span>
        </>
    )
}
export default Fav
```

Comment: Is `products` an array? Does `Fav` represent a single product? Seems like it's just for one product so how does it know about the others if the previous list of favourites isn't given as input? If you use Redux you can try adding to a list of favs there instead.

Comment: I added the product in my edit check it out, please.

Comment: seems like I could understand that Product is coming seperately as you said but my question is how can I put all of them together?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment each of your `Fav` components looks like they're trying to manage the state for *all of the favourites* which is not a good idea.

The general idea is to make most UI components as dumb as possible (ie. just return the bare minimum given the props they're given). They *can* control their own state but usually you want to a parent to control the state [by lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), and have them pass down a handler that the dumb component can call when their listener is triggered.

In this example `Fav` accepts an `id`, a `favoured`, and a `handleClick` listener, and then just returns some JSX.

The parent component does all the state management.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

// Accept some props
// Render the class based on the `favoured` prop
function Fav({ id, favoured, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <div className="icon">
      <i
        data-id={id}
        className={favoured ? 'fa-solid fa-heart' : 'fa-regular fa-heart'}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >&nbsp;{id}</i>
    </div>
  );
}

function Example() {

  // The parent component manages the state
  const [ favourites, setFavourites ] = useState([]);

  // When a favourite icon is clicked, get its id
  // and if it's in the state, remove it, otherwise add it
  function handleClick(e) {
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    const found = favourites.includes(id);
    if (found) {
      setFavourites(favourites.filter(fav => fav !== id));
    } else {
      setFavourites([...favourites, id]);
    }
  }

  // In this example I'm using a loop to generate the
  // the favourites, checking if the state includes the id
  // (I have to coerce it to a string because that's what
  // the data attributes return, and `i` will always be a number
  // Pass down the handler that the favourite button
  // will use to update the state
  function getFavs() {
    const favs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      const isFavoured = favourites.includes(i.toString());
      const fav = (
        <Fav
          id={i}
          favoured={isFavoured}
          handleClick={handleClick}
        />
      );
      favs.push(fav);
    }
    return favs;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {getFavs()}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```